# How to change the output of aggregate values in MongeDB

Tags: mongodb, boolean, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to write a Mongodb query that returns the name and income as highEarner `true` if income >70000 and `false` otherwise.

The documents I'm using have include, name (person's name), position(legal, HR, PR etc) and income (number).

The output I'm after is

```
{"name": "John Doe", HighEarner: true}, 
{"name": "John Loe", HighEarner: false}
```

This is how far I've gotten.

```
db.collection.aggregrate([
    {
      $group:{
        _id:"income", 
        "Honours":{true:{$income:$gt 70000}, {false;{$income:%lt 70000`}}
    }
}])
```

But its not working any pointers would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try the query below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: 1,
      HighEarner: {
        $gt: [
          "$income",
          70000
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hhPC5YShVvP)

Ref: [Operator Expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#operator-expressions)